# Cannot get DateTime.Now as string in Razor View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to get current time in a Razor View and use it in Javascript as shown below:

```
@{ 
    string fileName = "Score_List_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
}


<script>
    // assign C# variable to JavaScript variable.
    var FileName = @Html.Raw(@fileName);
</script>
```

And then I should be able to use it in a Javascript call as shown below:

```
...
{
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    text: FileName,
    title:'List', //title & file name
}
...
```

But encounter an error: *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(…)"*. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from hidden input:

```
@{ 
    string fileName = "Score_List_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
}

<input id="file-name" type="hidden" value="@fileName" />
```

In javascript:

```
...
{
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    text: $("#file-name").val(),
    title:'List', //title & file name
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It is completely unnecessary to use a hidden input here. The actual issue was in below line of code,

```html
<script>
    // assign C# variable to JavaScript variable.
    var FileName = @Html.Raw(@fileName);
</script>
```

You should have used single or double quotes around @Html.Raw(@fileName) to make it a string value in JS.

```html
<script>
    // assign C# variable to JavaScript variable.
    var FileName = '@Html.Raw(@fileName)';
</script>
```

Next time, if you encounter any error in dynamically generating JS script, you better check the generated code of page in browser.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any idea about the question containing Date?

Comment: @ClintEastwood, what is understand is you are talking about date format value in fileName variable. If yes then I assumed that date format in fileName would be valid file name.